# check if value contains any of const numbers? C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

What I am looking for isn't a problem solution but maybe a better c# logic.

Basically, I have a got a value which is a sum of any of those values {1, 2, 4}.
Then I will do some actions depends on those values in descending order.
Check the code below:

```
        byte value = 7;//could be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 which is the summation of any of those 3 numbers {1, 2, 4}
        bool case1 = false, case2 = false, case3 = false;
        if (value >= 4)
        {
            case1 = true;
            value -= 4;
        }
        if (value >= 3)
        {
            case2 = true;
            value -= 3;
        }
        if (value >= 1)
        {
            case3 = true;
            value -= 1;
        }
        if (case3)
        {
            //do some action
        }
        if (case2)
        {
            //do some action
        }
        if (case1)
        {
            //do some action
        }
```

Note that: Any of the numbers is not repeated in the summation.
That's what I have written in c#, But that doesn't make me feel good about the code logic in 2k17.

Hope someone has a better logic with any mathematical operation!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are using the word *summation* incorrectly. As it stands right now, your question is not clear for us to help you with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edited again... code sample)
Instead of using an int, could you use an enum?

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Nothing = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Four = 4,
    Seven = 7
}
MyEnum seven = MyEnum.Seven;

if( (seven & MyEnum.Four) == MyEnum.Four)
{
Console.WriteLine("Four");
}


if((seven & MyEnum.Two) == MyEnum.Two)
{
Console.WriteLine("Two");
}

if((seven & MyEnum.One) == MyEnum.One)
{
Console.WriteLine("One");
}
```

previous tip: bit masks, easy to understand examples here http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/07/26/enum-flags-and-bitwise-operators/

Comment: That's what exactly I was looking for as I never used bitmasks in c# tho I had no idea how to get that done. Thanks too much.

Answer (score 0):

I think your original code is wrong and the second `if` should be `if (value >= 2)` instead of `if (value >= 3)`, but that's beside the point. If I understand what you want to achieve then this console application should be of help:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value = 7;

        int copy = value; // only needed for the Console.WriteLine below

        var allComponents = new[] { 4, 2, 1 };

        var sumParts = new List<int>();
        int i = 0;

        while (i < allComponents.Length)
        {
            if (value >= allComponents[i])
            {
                value -= allComponents[i];
                sumParts.Add(allComponents[i]); // or do some action whatever you need
            }
            i++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Value {0} is the sum of {1}", copy, string.Join(" + ", sumParts));
    }
}
```

Outputs for the possible values (7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1):

```
Value 7 is the sum of 4 + 2 + 1
Value 6 is the sum of 4 + 2
Value 5 is the sum of 4 + 1
Value 4 is the sum of 4
Value 3 is the sum of 2 + 1
Value 2 is the sum of 2
Value 1 is the sum of 1
```

It's looping through all the components from largest to smallest (4, 2, 1), checking if the current one is larger or equal to the `value`, if yes, then decrements `value` by the current component and adds the current component to the `sumParts` list.

If you can invoke your logic from inside the if in the loop, then you don't even need the `sumParts`, just do whatever you need there.

This solution is basically the same as yours, but rolled into a loop instead of statements after each other.

Comment: Almost the same of my code but you have just changed the logic into looping, I have written it this way for easy understanding.
The issue is that it still checks for the value 4 if exists in the first stage but i have to check for the smallest value firstly.